# How to find Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix using Jacobi's method?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I came through a question while looking at a few past papers and was wondering how to fo it. I know how to solve a system of linear equations using the Jacobi Iterative method but how do you calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a 3x3 symmetric matrix using Jacobi's method?

I just need to know the procedure or an example so I can do it myself and not actual help with the exact question.I tried to find it on Google but it mostly turned out to be complex algorithmic procedures which I couldn't understand very well.

Comment: @Zero_Cool If you could look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method and address specific ambiguities we will be happy to elaborate.